# AKS Storage type with accessMode: ReadWriteMany that supports simultaneous writes from multiple pod at the same time

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, azure-aks

env: Azure/AKS v1.26

I want to find a solution to the problem described below:

I have multiple pods running in a multi-node AKS cluster (which are not necessarily running on the same node of the cluster) from which my application would need to write to a shared storage solution simultaneously.

I would need an Azure storage type that can be mounted as a volume to each of these pods on the /data path.

**What the application do?**
The application downloads a tar to a subdirectory (created separately by each pod with a unique identifier so every pod writes to its own folder) in the /data directory and extracts the tar in place.

**What have I checked?**

- Azure Files: supports simultaneous writes, but does not support extracting tar archives on the share.
- Azure Disk: does not support readWriteMany nor simultaneous writes from multiple pods.
- Shared Azure Disk: supports readWriteMany, but does not support simultaneous writes, only 1 pod at a time.

Thanks in advance for all the support!

Comment: When deploying to Kubernetes, you better design your app to be "cloud native", and hence avoid using a shared volume. Make your instances to work independently of eachother.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas for your comment! I can totally agree with you, but redesigning the app is not an option atm. The app works "independently" in a way that any one pods writing to the shared storage does not depend on the data written to the volume by any other pods. Without the attached storage pods are using the disk available on the node which we are running out of in some cases and the only option I have found to increase the disk available on an AKS node is to change the type of the node to a larger SKU but that would greatly increase the cost while we dont need extra cpu/ram as of now.